# React Native : Display User Data in textInput field

Tags: firebase, expo, react-native, react-native-firebase

I am trying to display user data in the text input field so the user can not either update it or leave it as it is,
actually, I successfully displayed the data but the problem is that the user can edit it.
here is how I did it.

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);
  const [FullName, setFullName] = useState(null);
```

**here I get the user data and store it in Userdata stata**

```
 const getUserData = async () => {
    await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
      .get()
      .then((documentSnapshot) => {
        if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
          setUserData(documentSnapshot.data());
        }
      });
  };
```

**her I am updating the user data**

```
  const UpdateImage = async () => {
    setUpdate(true);
    let imgUrl = await uploadImageToBucket();
   await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
      .update({
        photoURL: imgUrl,
        displayName: FullName ,
        Email: Email,
        description: Description,
        age: Age,
      })
      .then(() => navigation.navigate("UserProfileScreen"))
      .catch((err) => {
        alert(err, "Please Select a Photo First");
        setUploading(false);
        setUpdate(false);
      });
  };
```

**here I am displaying the previous data in text input field**

```
<TextInput
            style={styles.textInput}
            placeholder="Update Your FullName...."
            value={userData ? userData.displayName : ''}
            onChangeText={(txt) => setFullName({...userData, FullName: txt})}
          />
```

**the name I actually displayed in the text input field but I can't edit it any help please**

Comment: When the user can not either update it or leave it as it is, what should the user do ?

Comment: Pretty sure you need to set it as `defaultValue` instead of `value`

Comment: how can I do that